# How to fetch rows by descending order by appears number?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, descendant

I'm asking if there are a possibility to order results by a descendant order of number of appearance of rows, an example to clarify:
here are my table:

```
foo
foo1
foo
foo
foo1
foo2
```

here is my result after a query (that I cant guess) call:

```
foo 
foo 
foo 
foo1
foo1
foo2
```

coz foo apears 3 times then foo1 that apears 2 times and then foo2 apears just 1 times.

So, how the query used look like?

I'll appreciate any support!
My regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t1.col from
table as t1 inner join (
select col,count(col) as num
from table 
group by col) as t2
on t1.col = t2.col
order by t2.num desc
```

Comment: This part of the query "select col,count(col) as num
from table 
group by col" gives you each single value and its number of occurrences (try to run it to see the result). Since you want all the single records, you have to make a join between your table and the query I wrote you above. Finally you sort in descending order the result by the number of occurrences you have found with that query.

Comment: @nick rulez, your first query did the purpose (without 'join'), great for you! thank you a looooot!

Comment: coz what I wanted in fact is to show each row with it's number of appearance, the thing you did it!